# iPhone : pushing on UIViewController from where it pushed

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I've two `UIViewControllers` say `ViewController_A` and `ViewController_B`

My flow is, **A**`ViewController_A` ---> **B**`ViewController_B` ---> **C**`ViewController_A`

For A, B and C navigations I have the following situation,

**A** - In `ViewController_A` I've 100 of records which are in `UITableViewCell`, user select any one, and it will pushed to `ViewController_B` which will showing that selected record from `ViewController_A`.

**B** - Will show selected data from `ViewController_A`, and having Back button to go back (I can pop). Another thing, have a `UIButton`, If user tap this, it will again showing `ViewController_A` but with only that single record

**C** - Either we'll pop from `ViewController_B` then there's no issue, but I again want to push, so I need to `#import` `ViewController_A` in `ViewController_B` (as I've already imported `ViewController_B` in `ViewController_A` so I can't reimport `ViewController_A` in `ViewController_B`, right?) will create collision for those `UIViewControllers`.

What should be the better way to solve the problem in **C**, one suggestion is to make another `` `ViewController_D `` like and show the same as in `ViewController_A` but I think its not proper way, as I've already `UI` and `coded` for the functionality.

Suggestion needed. Let me know if you've any doubt!

Comment: What I think use a common array to load tableview in Viewcontroller A and use two different arrays to overwrite the common array depending on the situation. And use delegate for the button in viewcontrollerB that will reload the tableview in viewcontroller A where in delagate just overwrite the common array with only single record and pressing on that button of viewcontroller B pop the viewcontroller. Hope it may help you little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I understand is you have trouble with #import directive ? 
I guess you are importing header in the .h file ? If so, do an #import in the .m file; and in the .h you should use @class YouViewControllerA.

Ex with AViewController:

**.h**

```
@class BViewController

@interface AViewController : UIViewController 
{
  //Your attributes here
}

@end
```

**.m**

```
#import "BViewController.h"

@implementation AViewController

//Some AViewController methods here

@end
```

Do this for both AViewController and BViewController and it should work.

**EDIT :** #import directives are designed to avoid recursive error, so anyway you shouldn't get error.
If you know a bit of preprocessing, the #import do the following (automatically) :

```
#ifndef TOTO_HEADER
#define TOTO_HEADER

//your methods here

#endif
```

**More explanation :**

When you write #import "toto.h" , at compile time the compiler will do the following check :

- Is the preprocessoring variable "TOTO_HEADER" defined ? (this corresponding to the line ifndef "TOTO_HEADER")
- If it isn't we define it (this is the #define "TOTO_HEADER" line) AND we "include" the methods and functions.
- If it has been already defined, no need to include the methods (since they already get included).

This way we prevent header file from being included if they were already included. (and by extension it should not make any recursive error).

In other words : #import ensures that a header file is only included once so that you never have a problem with recursive includes.

Comment: Ashbay, I know this soln, but as in my question would it be feasible to do like this!! We're importing both files in both viewcontrollers for pushing. Would it not create any problem?

Comment: It shouldn't create any problem (see my edit for more information). Hope it will help.

Comment: Ashbay, oh, that's good edit & pointing! Can you explain me little more about this? How it will actually working?

Answer (score 0):

one solution could be this-

First save the selected value in NSUserDefaults, and then take a bool when you click on the UIButton in viewController B.
Then push a segue to ViewController A and check the value of Bool there.
If its true then only print the value of NSUserDefaults else print the whole set of 100 records.

Comment: Yes, the question is about pushing, please read the question again, the problem is not how to showing the data, its of pushing the viewcontrollers.

Comment: then wats the problem if you can push from A to b similarly you can Push from B to A. I don't see any problem in it

Comment: okay, I need to import B into A, and A into B for pushing right? My question is that, would it create any problem? Any recursion issue or any kind of problem? Read point **C**.

Comment: i dont think so because if you are using a segue you need to import the destination view controller. So, it should not create any problems according to me